# About the order of Coxeter groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-presentation, coxeter-groups, combinatorial-group-theory

I have a question about Coxeter groups with $3$ generators:

> Suppose, as a group, $G$ is generated by $a,b$ and $c$, with the relations $a^2 =b^2 =c^2 =1$, $(ab)^m = (bc)^n = (ca)^p =1$ where $2 \leq m,n,p < \infty$. When is $G$ finite?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_group

Comment: The finite Coxeter groups of rank 3 are $A_3$, $C_3$, and $H_3$. WLOG assume $m\ge n\ge p$. A quick check involving the associated Gram matrix shows these correspond to $m=3,n=3,p=2$; $m=4,n=3,p=2$; and $m=5,n=3,p=2$. All others are either (i) reducible or (ii) infinite. The reducible cases are $m=?,n=2,p=2$.

Comment: And the reducible ones are finite of order $4m$.